# Error opening connection connect ECONNREFUSED (Source: SQLTools (extention))

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

I get this error whenever I try to connect to my database using VSCode.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extensions but it didn't work.

Comment: first check if the database is running, second check if user name and password exist, for example use workbench to access the database

Comment: @nbk Wrong user name or password would not result in a `ECONNREFUSED`, which basically means the OP is attempting to connect to a TCP/IP port that isn't open.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel first we must establish if he has a server at all

Comment: @nbk Definitely true, but my comment was in response to your _"second check if user name and password exist"_.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i told to use datase tp establish the credentials, so if he can connct he has all information that vs code needs to., and all have some kind of tutorial to use workbench,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.